# asyncio python with serial device takes 100% CPU

Tags: python, epoll, python-asyncio

When I run this little main from [rfxcom python library](https://github.com/d0ugal-archive/python-rfxcom) :

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop
from rfxcom.transport import AsyncioTransport

dev_name = '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-RFXCOM_RFXtrx433_A1XZI13O-if00-port0'
loop = get_event_loop()

def handler(packet):
    print(packet.data)

try:
    rfxcom = AsyncioTransport(dev_name, loop, callback=handler)
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

I see that CPU usage is getting very hight (around 100%).
I can't understand why : there is very few messages (~ 1 message every 5 seconds) received by the module, and I thought that when [epoll_wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) was called then the CPU should be idled, waiting for the next event.

I launched the main with python cProfile, and it shows this :

```
In [4]: s.sort_stats('time', 'module').print_stats(50)
Mon Jul 20 22:20:55 2015    rfxcom_profile.log

     263629453 function calls (263628703 primitive calls) in 145.437 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, file name
   List reduced from 857 to 50 due to restriction <50>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 13178675   37.280    0.000  141.337    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py:1076(_run_once)
 13178675   31.114    0.000   53.230    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/selectors.py:415(select)
 13178674   15.115    0.000   32.253    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/selector_events.py:479(_process_events)
 13178675   12.582    0.000   12.582    0.000 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}
 13178699   11.462    0.000   17.138    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py:1058(_add_callback)
 13178732    6.397    0.000   11.397    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py:118(_run)
 26359349    4.872    0.000    4.872    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
        1    4.029    4.029  145.365  145.365 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py:267(run_forever)
 13178669    4.010    0.000    4.913    0.000 /home/bruno/src/DomoPyc/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rfxcom-0.3.0-py3.4.egg/rfxcom/transport/asyncio.py:85(_writer)
```

So the first three function calls in term of elapsed time are `python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py`, `python3.4/selectors.py` and `python3.4/asyncio/selector_events.py`.

***EDIT*** : the time command on a similar run gives :

```
time python -m cProfile -o rfxcom_profile.log rfxcom_profile.py
real    2m24.548s
user    2m19.892s
sys     0m4.113s
```

Can someone explain me why ?

***EDIT2***: As the the number of fonctions calls is very high, I made a strace of the process and found that there is a loop on epoll_wait with a timeout value of 2ms :

```
// many lines like this :
epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=7, u64=537553536922157063}}}, 2, -1) = 1
```

I saw in base_event._run_once that the timeout is calculated, but I can't figure it out. I don't know how to set this timeout higher to lower the CPU.

If someone has a clue...

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It's spending most of its time in `select`, which is unsurprising because that's basically sleeping between events.  On Unixy systems, the command `time` can show whether a process is I/O bound or CPU bound.  Its output would be helpful in diagnosing this issue.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, and yes I didn't think of the time command. I'm going to edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer my question as it may be usefull for others.

After having set the environment variable `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG` to 1, there was lines and lines like :

```
 DEBUG:asyncio:poll took 0.006 ms: 1 events
```

In the Rfxcom library there is a writer mechanism with a queue to push data to the serial device. The intention was I think *"asyncio, tell me when I can write, and then I'll flush the write queue"*. So there was a line like this :

```
self.loop.call_soon(self.loop.add_writer, self.dev.fd, self._writer)
```

`self.dev` is the `Serial` class instance and `self.dev.fd` is the serial file descriptor.

As [the doc says](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) *"add_writer(fd, callback, *args) : Start watching the file descriptor for write availability"*.

I thought that a serial device was always available for writing so I made a little script:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

loop = get_event_loop()

def writer_cb():
    logger.info("writer cb called")

s = Serial('/dev/serial/by-id/usb-RFXCOM_RFXtrx433_A1XZI13O-if00-port0', 38400, timeout=1)

loop.add_writer(s.fd, writer_cb)
loop.run_forever()
```

And saw the lines looping endlessly, bringing CPU to 100%:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:poll took 0.006 ms: 1 events
INFO:root:writer cb called
```

So I think there is no need to put a writer callback, but simply call `write` on the serial device.